# how to create an inner shadow of an image using easeljs

Tags: dropshadow, easeljs

it's easy to make an inner shadow in Actionscript.

just use

```
var myShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter();
myShadow.inner = true;
```

how to do it with easeljs? Is it not implemented?

Comment: Yes, not implemented.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
anyone knows when the next release will be?
I am looking forward to the blending modes.
The current createjs really doesn't do much...
very disappointed.